# Is there any way to have the android and ios meta tags for Facebook invite on the same page?

Tags: php, android, ios, iphone, facebook

For my Facebook app invite url, when I have the meta tags for Android and iOS on the same page, it doesn't work, but when I put them on seperate pages it does work. Is there any way to have the meta tags all on the same page?

```
    <meta property="al:android:url" content="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=*****&hl=en">
<meta property="al:android:package" content="*****">
<meta property="al:android:app_name" content="*****">
<meta property="og:title" content="example page title" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />

<meta property="al:ios:url" content="https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/*****/id*****?mt=8" />
<meta property="al:ios:app_store_id" content="*****" />
<meta property="al:ios:app_name" content="*****" />
<meta property="og:title" content="example page title" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
```

Obviously I have replaced where my app id / name is with *****

Comment: please add your code so we know what you are talking about.

Comment: I'e added it on there

Comment: that should work, make sure you aren't doubling the `og:title` and `og:type` tag

Comment: It's strange because it is working on Android when I send the invite from Android, but when I send the invite from iOS I get no notification on iOS. Could it be that I haven't added the app store id yet to Facebook because my app hasn't been released on iOS yet?